# cross browser rendering explain plans

Tags: internet-explorer, firefox, google-chrome, cross-browser, sql-execution-plan

I was hoping to be able to find a tool,application or script that takes IE vs Chrome or IE vs Firefox etc...and renders them, then offers an explanation as to what the difference between the two are, if such a tool even exists.

I've found tools like ie tester which offers some help in testing dif versions of ie, but not quite what i'm looking for. I've inherited a large and complex internal site that I'm looking to clean up for cross browser compatibility and was hoping that I could use something like I described.

Thanks for your assistance,

Chris

Comment: I doubt that a such a tool exists. You want it to look at the site and tell you what differences exist between different browsers? Would you like it to code the website too ;) ?

Comment: haha that would be fantastic :P naa...i'm running into some difficulty of some major differences between ie and firefox (go figure) and was hoping that something would be able to offer an explanation, since i've pretty much exhausted all of my ideas as to whats going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Browsershots.org](http://browsershots.org/) will show you how they look in different browsers, but there is no tool that will explain why they look different.  That's what you get paid to figure out.